# What is the best way to have different social share cards from the same page?

Tags: javascript, facebook, twitter, social-media

I have created a basic personality quiz in JavaScript that has four outcomes. I want to make it where people can share their results after they complete the quiz, but I'm not sure the best way to do it. The solution would need to be HTML/CSS/Javascript based, as I'm doing this on a CMS.

I thought about setting up separate pages with redirects, but I'd rather avoid redirects if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Difference share info means different URLs with different Open Graph tags. You cannot set them with JavaScript, because Facebook would ignore it. So you can either use separate pages with separate tags, or use parameters and change the tags server side. For example: `yourdomain.com/somepage.php?id=1`